# Node-RED on bluemix giving 404 for http input node

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I've put three http input nodes onto a tab in Node-RED on Bluemix.  I've tried naming them various things, and I can only get one of them to actually work.  The others give a 404.  I've put the name from an iteration that worked on the failing nodes and they still fail.  I've put the name from a failing node on the working node and it still works.  I've tried deleting the nodes, re-adding them, stopping/restarting Node-RED.  Is there something obvious that I should try?

Comment: edit the question to include more information, such as what you put in the config window (maybe a screen shot) and what URL you tried to access. Also did you ensure the url started with a '/'

Comment: Figured this out by looking at the Cloudant database.  The two failing nodes were missing the "/".